# suclassing a UIButton of type .system

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to subclass UIButton, but i want it to be of type .system. I am struggling with initializers

```
class FormButton: UIButton {

var type FormButtonType: FormButtomType.oneSelection

init(oftype formType: FormButtomType) {
    self.type = formType
    super.init(type: .system)
}

}
```

problem is that I have the following error message : "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIButton'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override a convenience method and call super convenience method... 
As an alternative you can do a static method that return a `FormButton` of `UIButtonType.system` type.

```
class FormButton: UIButton {
    class func newButton() -> FormButton {
        return FormButton.init(type: .system)
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
let button = FormButton.newButton()
```

Comment: That's what I was supecting...  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you need the `System type` because of the highlighted animation behaviour.
If so, You can `override` the `Highlighted` property in your `UIButton` subclass like so:

```
var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            // If you have images in your button, add them here same as the code below
            (self.isHighlighted && self.titleLabel != nil) ? (self.titleLabel!.alpha = 0.2) : (self.titleLabel!.alpha = 1.0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's the only reason why I wanted the system type and works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

The error is little bit confusing

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIButton'

but what it is trying to say is that you need to call designated initialiser before using `self`. So shift `self.type` call after `super.init` call. You have created a `convenience` initialiser which doesn't require call to super, you need to call `self`.

First of all, this line is syntactically wrong.

```
 var type FormButtonType: FormButtomType.oneSelection
```

should be be

```
 var type: FormButtonType = FormButtomType.oneSelection
```

Now you can subclass it easily.

```
import UIKit

class FormButton: UIButton {

    var type: FormButtonType = FormButtomType.oneSelection

    // convenence initializer, simply call self if you have
    // initialized type
    convenience init(type: UIButtonType) {
        self.init(type: type)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now if you want to initialise some property which doesn't have default or optional value then you will need to `override` the designated initialiser.

For Example,

```
class FormButton: UIButton {

    var type: UIButtonType = UIButtonType.system
    var hello: String // property doesn't have initial value

    // This is designated initialiser
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.hello = "Hello"

        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    convenience init(type: UIButtonType) {
        self.init(type: .system)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at my code, I am already using super.init. I Think that the problem is that the super.init(type: .system) is not a designated initializer ...

Comment: @user3239711 Sorry I misread the question. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -3):

You need to the call superclass' designated initializer:

```
init(oftype formType: FormButtomType) {

    super.init(frame: yourframe)
    self.type = formType

}
```

Comment: But if I do that, how can I have a UIButton of type .system (the property is read only)